# How to count null row with $_GET in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm now trying to count a click to get Popular Post Counter from reader, but I get problem with How to count it since previous row has no value or null.

Here's my codes:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("conndb.php");

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $idClick=$_GET['id'];
    }

$qryClick = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ra_articlez WHERE id=:$idClick");
$qryClick->execute();
$varClick = $qryClick->fetchAll();
foreach ($varClick as $echoClick) {
    $contID=$echoClick['id'];
    $cntentqry=$echoClick['count'];
    $imgqry=$echoClick['timestamp'];

    $sql="UPDATE ra_articlez SET count=count+1 WHERE id = :idClick";
    echo $cntentqry; // can not echo the result
    }
?>
```

Do you have better than it does? please suggest me, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you doing here??

```
WHERE id=:$idClick
```

What you want to do is set a bind param and then execute by passing the arguments within the `execute()` function.

```
$qryClick = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ra_articlez WHERE id=:idClick");
$qryClick->execute(array(':idClick' => $idClick));
```

You should really read the documentation, because you aren't doing it correctly.

And what exactly are you trying to do in your `foreach()` loop?

Comment: O my god! I can't believe it I missed to bind it! thanks .. it works!
I use loop just for the test if it works. thanks

Comment: so, count=count+1 is true, right? and I don't need to write: count=:$cntentqry+1 ?

Comment: @JeanGkol That should work if you're only incrementing it by 1 each time.

Comment: @JeanGkol Pleasure mate.